# Upload a file and write version history comment using a custom "Author" / "Editor using C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, office-365

I'm trying to **programmatically upload** a file to SharePoint (2016)/ office 365 and modify the Created by /Modified by and also add a history comment along with this operation.  The idea is I cannot make those things work together in the same operation.

I can modify the created by with the following code.

```
uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["Editor"] = userValue.Id;
uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["Author"] = userValue.Id;
```

But in order to add a history comment I must check out/check in the file.

```
uploadFile.CheckOut();
uploadFile.CheckIn("Just a history comment", CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);
```

This overrides my previous changes and my Author and Editor is set to my account, doesn't matter what I do.

There are other approaches that I'm missing ?

Comment: So, just to confirm since you only mention this in the tags - you are using Client side object model against a SharePoint online 2016 farm?

Comment: Yes .I'm using client side object model.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to be sure. I can't really think of a way to achieve this (CSOM doesn't support .SystemUpdate() ) but let me check anyway. Will report if I can find something noteworthy.

Comment: What about user impersonation? Is a user defined in config or is a variable user depending on context, time, whatever?

Comment: The user is variable that get from database.... A solution in this case can be to put a custom password for all users and after the operation is done to force the users to change their passwords.

Comment: What about Microsoft graph API solution? It is possible ? In my case the SharePoint will be on cloud office 365 .

Comment: The **ClientContext** is build for current user and Office 365 automatically manages while updating document. I suggest create your own specific 'User' column with custom names !! Actually, I struggled with fetching the old versions data but in vain. So its better, not to use SharePoint default user columns for this kind of scenarios.